# Why am i getting a error in this java code? Im just a beginner learning java

Tags: java, multithreading

public class Thread{

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    
}
```

}

Thread.java:9: error: cannot find symbol

```
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

                             ^
```

symbol:   method currentThread()
location: class Thread
1 error

Comment: your class is named `Thread`, it does not have the static method `currentThread()` - that would be in the class `java.lang.Thread`, but your class is hiding it - change the name of your class (it is not a good idea, not recommended to use same name as standard classes) {you could also use `java.lang.Thread.currentThread()`}

Answer (score 0):

user16320675 is correctly pointing out. It is happening because you named your class as "Thread", to solve this problem, either rename your class (eg. to MyThread or Test etc) **Or** use java.lang.Thread for invoking currentThread() Method on it (to use java's Thread class instead of yours).
Find the code below :

```
public class MyThread{
   public static void main(String[] args){      
     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());      
   }
}
```

Or

```
public class Thread{
    public static void main(String[] args){     
       System.out.println(java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getName());      
    }
}
```